# Showing that $1 + \sqrt{5}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$

Tags: ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. How can we show that the element $1 + \sqrt{5}$ is irreducible in this ring?

Comment: Maybe show that product of 2 elements in that ring is never $1+\sqrt{5}$

Answer (score 1):

First, since $N(1+\sqrt{5})=1^2-1^2\cdot 5=-4$, we have that $1+\sqrt{5}$ is not a unit.  Thus $1+\sqrt{5}=xy$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, and suppose that neither are units.  What does this tell us about, say, $N(x)$?  Since $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)=-4$, it follows $N(x)=\pm 2$.  If $x=a+b\sqrt{5}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $a^2-5b^2=\pm 2$, hence $a^2\pmod{5}\in\{2,3\}$.  This is a contradiction (can you see why?)  Hence one of $x,y$ is a unit and $1+\sqrt{5}$ is indeed irreducible.

Comment: I follow this proof up to "can you see why?" Could you maybe elaborate on why there cannot be $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a^2 - 5b^2 = \pm 2$?

Comment: Let's look at the $+2$ case.  Suppose $a^2-5b^2=2$.  Then $a^2-2=5b^2$, which implies $a^2\equiv 2\pmod{5}$.  In equivalence class notation, this implies $[a^2]_5=[2]_5$, where $[x]_5$ represents the equivalence class of $x$.  But since $[a^2]_5=[a]^2_5$, this implies $[a]_5^2=[2]_5$, a contradiction.  We can check the squares of all elements in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ by hand to see this.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Suppose $1 + \sqrt{5} = xy$. What can be norms of $x$ and $y$ be?

Comment: Well $N(1 + \sqrt{5}) = 6$ so we must have $N(x)N(y) = 6$

Comment: Ehh, $N(a + b\sqrt{5}) = a^2 - 5b^2$.